# Can I rename my PSN account?

Tags: psn

Is it possible to change the online ID associated with my PSN account? If it's possible, how do I go about changing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Yes, since April 10, 2019, you can now change your PSN name.](https://www.monergism.com/thethreshold/sdg/Trinitarian%20Heresies.html)

First, be aware that you can only do so once for free. After that, each change will cost you $5/£4 if you're a PS Plus subscriber or $10/£8 if you're not. You can also call support to change back to any of your previous names for free however.

Changing your name is also only guaranteed to work for games published since April 1, 2018. Most older games, PS3 games, and Vita games will have issues, and you might lose game progress or DLC. [Here is a good video going over some of the issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4dXpW4sIg8), but to summarize some examples: Little Big Planet and Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare surprisingly work fine with the new name, Grand Theft Auto 4 and Modern Warfare 2 treat it as a new PSN account, and Black Ops 2 completely fails to load if you're signed in and can irreversibly corrupt your PS3's hard drive if your try signing in with the game running. So, uh, yeah, be careful.

Now on to how to do it, as taken from [Sony's help article](https://coid.support.playstation.com/s/howto):

> #### Change Your Online ID from Your PlayStation®4
>
> Step 1: From your PS4 go to [Settings].
>   Step 2: Select [Account Management] > [Account Information] >
>   [Profile] > [Online ID].
>   Step 3: Enter your new online ID.
>   Step 4: Follow the on-screen prompts to complete the change.
>   Once you complete the change process, you are signed out from all your
>   devices.
>
> #### Change Your Online ID from a Web Browser
>
> Step 1: Sign in to [PlayStation™ Network Account Management](https://id.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/id/management/#/p/psn_profile/) and select
>   PSN Profile in the menu.
>   Step 2: Click Edit button next to your current online ID.
>   Step 3: Enter your new online ID.
>   Step 4: Follow the on-screen prompts to complete the change.
>   Once you complete the change process, you are signed out from all your
>   devices.

Any further questions can probably be answered by [Sony's FAQ on the subject](https://coid.support.playstation.com/s/faqs).

Comment: Beat me to it. Support link if you want to add it in: http://us.playstation.com/support/answer/index.htm?a_id=254

Comment: Not keeping trophies and stats is enough reason not to do it, but for completeness' sake, what about purchases in the PSN store?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: You couldn't keep PlayStation Plus, and you couldn't redownload anything, but I can't find any info on whether or not already installed content will remain or get deactivated. I would think that it would still work, but I don't know about some things like multiplayer maps and PSN games.

Comment: And I also assume that you'd lose your multiplayer serials (online pass, passport, whatever they're called) and e.g. a link to your Steam account.