# How to remove psn account from ps3

Tags: achievements, ps3, ps4, psn

When I got the ps3 I had a different psn account then I do on my ps4. I want to remove the psn account from my ps3, but since I had loads of trophies(achievements) that I got before a psn account was added I want to be able to put a new psn account (the one on the ps4) on that profile and keep the trophies.

Comment: I believe this is addressed in the answer here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166393/can-i-transfer-trophies-and-data-to-a-new-account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I transfer trophies and data to a new account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166393/can-i-transfer-trophies-and-data-to-a-new-account)